# Broadcast messages using JMSComponent

Tags: queue, jms, apache-camel

I have a problem where I have to broadcast messages to different output locations. I am using JMSComponent for configuring my output queues. My output queues configuration have something like this:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = createOrGetConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration();
jmsConfiguration.setPreserveMessageQos(true);
jmsConfiguration.setConnectionFactory(factory);

counter++;
outputLocations = new StringBuilder("hubOutput"+counter+":queue://queueName");
JmsEndpoint endpoint = new JmsEndpoint();
JmsComponent component = new JmsComponent();
component.setConcurrentConsumers(5);
component.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration);
component.setConnectionFactory(factory);

//Add new JMS component in the context. This is done so that the output locations having same queue can be differentiated using the component name in camel registry.                       getContext().addComponent("hubOutput"+counter, component);
endpoint = (JmsEndpoint) component.createEndpoint(outputLocations.toString());
endpoint.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration);
```

I have a camel route for broadcasting the messages to the output queues.

```
from(fromLocation)
    .setHeader("hubRoutesList",constant(hubUrl))
    .log(urlToLog)
    .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly)
    .multicast()
    .parallelProcessing()
    .to(hubUrl.split(","));
```

All the output queues have different broker URL but same queue name.
The code works normally but if one of the queues is down, then the message is not broadcasted to other queues also.

Kindly help me with this.

Thanks,
Richa

Answer (score 1):

You can use the recipientList instead of .to(hubUrl.split(","));

With the option stopOnException=false, which is the defaultValue, the forwarding of the messages to the other endpoints will not stop even if one of your queues is down. 
See http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html for  more information.